# VSCode multiple copy-paste?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any feature similar to the one found in Visual Studio for pasting from the clipboard history?
Its a nice feature that increases productivity in some circumstances.
For example, if I use ctrl + c many times for several texts, then I can use a shortcut to paste all these texts.
In Visual Studio, we can use ctrl + shift + v.

Comment: Maybe: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=slevesque.vscode-multiclip

Comment: Your operating system?

Comment: @Mark, I use window 7

Comment: I found this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SirTobi.code-clip-ring

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The best plugin I found: Multiple clipboards for VSCode.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=slevesque.vscode-multiclip

It looks better than the usual <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> I was looking for.
In addition to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to Merge-Copy.
And <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to Merge-Cut.
Select clipboard to paste (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>).
Paste and cycle through clipboard items (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>).

Comment: I am using VS Code February 2020 (version 1.43). This extension is not working. I have installed it using the extension manager. When I do multiple copies and tries to paste it using ctrl + shift + v, it doesn't paste anything.

Comment: It is working now, Actually, there was an extension "Markdown All in One" was having some feature with same keyboard binding. I have changed its keyboard binding with some other shortcut. Now, this extension is working fine.

Answer (score 23):

Are you using Windows 10/11? If so, you can use the multi clipboard by pressing WIN + V
I use it everyday and i think its the most **native** Clipboard Solution for windows 10/11 users.

Comment: This is a valid answer (so I won't downvote), but could be a security issue. If you use the windows history it will remember EVERYTHING you copy and paste and it brings it up in the UI. Not great if you're showing your screen.

Comment: I remembers it of course, but when you logout or reboot the PC it will be purged. So i still think this answer is valid. Look at those extensions in vscode, they all do the same as well, showing you options of what you have copied so far.

Answer (score 6):

I found this one, it's really simplistic. One clipboard history, no configuration, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> shows the dropdown from which you can pick your paste.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Anjali.clipboard-history

Answer (score 4):

I use this one:

1. Save history of all copied and cut items
2. Can check copied items outside the VSCode ("clipboard-manager.onlyWindowFocused": false)
3. Paste from history (Ctrl+Shift+V => Pick and Paste)
4. Preview the paste
5. Snippets to paste (Ex. clip01, clip02, ...)
6. Remove selected item from history
7. Clear all history
8. Open copy location
9. Double click in history view to paste

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EdgardMessias.clipboard-manager

Comment: This one is great because it a.) does not override the default ctrl+c/v actions, b.) enables snippets for autosuggestions and c.) has a preview option

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good Visual Studio Code Extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TechnoFunnel.multiplecopypaste

This is added new to the extension store.

you will have options to copy 10 values and paste 10 value

Comment: This one is the most useful one when it comes to multiple copy and paste.