# VSCode Copy Paste list of words while keeping general structure

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']

# Colors:
# Red = #FF0000
# Green = #00FF00
# Blue = #0000FF
```

How would I copy the hex values from the comments into the list while keeping the `'...'` and the general structure of the list?

[Video Example in Sublimetext](https://youtu.be/MPiz50TsyF0?t=392)

Comment: Not exactly the same but this may help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408487/vscode-multiple-copy-paste

Comment: read about multi cursor